# R aggregate dataframe by intervals

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with

-time in seconds (integer)

-boolean value

I'm trying to aggregate the time to 60 sec intervals (0-59, 60-119, .... 11940-12000) to get the following dataframe:

-timeframe (n-th minute)

-number of elements of that timeframe

-number of elements of that timeframe where the boolean value was true

i looked into aggregate, sum, group_by and cut but don't understand how to solve my problem.

Thanks for everyone willing to help me!

EDIT:
output of  `dput(head(data, 20))`:

structure(list(time = c(5321L, 5320L, 5276L, 5275L, 5275L, 5269L,
5252L, 5195L, 5193L, 5190L, 5184L, 5177L, 5164L, 5146L, 5123L,
5118L, 5100L, 5085L, 5081L, 5062L), boolean = c(FALSE, TRUE,
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = 18:37, class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please post data in `dput` format. Post the output of `dput(head(data, 20))` in the question, where `data` is the name of your data.frame.

Comment: I edited my post, did I do what you wanted correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut`/`findInterval` to divide data into 60 seconds interval and count number of rows in each group and `sum` `boolean` value to get count where `boolean` value is `TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(grp = findInterval(time, seq(min(time), max(time), 60))) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), 
            n_true = sum(boolean))
```

Comment: thanks, looks good so far. I only see the first 10 rows tho and don't know how to safe the tiddle (bcs of the 'data %>%' i guess)

Comment: @Solaire You need to assign the data back to new object. `data1 <- data %>%
  group_by(grp = findInterval.....` and then check `data1`.